# Redux action on .then promise of another very slow

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a redux action set up that posts to an external API, this updates a database, and returns the updated results. I then run another function inside to check a database table for new results:

```
this.props.updateAddTest(payload)
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.error) {

    } else {



      let payloadTwo = { 
        parentTestId: this.state.parentTestId,
        bespokeTestId: response.response.testId,
        selectedTests: selectedTests,
      }

      page.props.loadAvailableTests(payloadTwo)
      .then((response) => {

        page.setState({checkInvalidTests: response.response})

      })
    } 
})
```

Running this code makes the network response time around 10 seconds - why does it take so long? Running the functions separately, it takes around 200ms. e.g just running:

```
this.props.updateAddTest(payload);
```

Why does nesting one redux action inside another slow it down so much?

Comment: You might want to check if it's the actual _request_ that is slow since you're measuring the network response time.

Comment: If I check the API request in postman it also only takes around 200ms. Also doing a javascript fetch request outside of react/redux also returns similar results.

Comment: Did you check that your function isn't accidentally called multiple times in your component's life cycle?

Comment: The function is called on click - So only runs once

Comment: Something is weird there. You might want to either: re-analyse where your functions are from and refactor your logic to try to prevent going deep like that into a redux action, or update your react-redux.